# Emails delivered, but no where to be found

Tags: centos, email, postfix, dovecot

I have been working on this for 2 days now and am desperate for some help.

```
Postfix & Dovecot 
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009
Plesk 18.0.50
```

For the most part emails are flowing into the server correctly - however I have an odd scenario where ***some*** emails that come through our external spam filter and flow through an account that's a forward or an alias, they do not actually end up in the users mailbox.

This is an example of one of the emails I have traced this morning:

**From Mail Assure Spam Filter Log**

```
1pZZdb-0002Mt-IH
myolddomain.com
2023-03-07 07:54
notify@payments.interac.ca
luke
allowlisted
INTERAC e-Transfer: LUKE PITTMAN cancelled the money transfer sent to you.
delivered
```

The columns for the data above should be rather obvious, but basically it confirms that my server received the email (delivered) from Mail Assure (the external spam filtering service).

**Matching email from /var/log/maillog**

```
Mar  7 07:54:29 server postfix/smtpd[27797]: connect from delivery.mtaroutes.com[185.201.16.200]
Mar  7 07:54:30 server postfix/smtpd[27797]: CB260BC4006B: client=delivery.mtaroutes.com[185.201.16.200]
Mar  7 07:54:31 server postfix/cleanup[28935]: CB260BC4006B: message-id=<248542808.92042284.1678204442900@6ea0c801e2d0>
Mar  7 07:54:31 server postfix/qmgr[14249]: CB260BC4006B: from=<notify@payments.interac.ca>, size=62814, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  7 07:54:31 server postfix/pipe[28941]: CB260BC4006B: to=<luke@myolddomain.com>, relay=plesk_virtual, delay=0.67, delays=0.63/0/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via plesk_virtual service)
Mar  7 07:54:31 server postfix/qmgr[14249]: CB260BC4006B: removed
Mar  7 07:54:31 server postfix/smtpd[27797]: disconnect from delivery.mtaroutes.com[185.201.16.200] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=2 quit=1 commands=8
```

But that's it... the email does **not** end up in the mailbox (anywhere, inbox, spam folders, etc)

```
-bash-4.2# cd /var/qmail/mailnames/mynewdomain.com/luke
-bash-4.2# grep -R CB260BC4006B ./*
-bash-4.2#
```

I also ran back to the root directory and ran the same command with no results as well, so it's literally nowhere to be found on the server.

To prove to myself that the above command does work when finding an email, I ran it on an email that actually went through:

```
-bash-4.2# grep -R 134D4BC4006F ./*
./Maildir/cur/1678205924.M212491P6629.server.mydomain.com,S=7790,W=7925:2,: id 134D4BC4006F; Tue,  7 Mar 2023 08:18:44 -0800 (PST)
```

To add to the confusion - when I remove the external spam filter from the loop, the above emails have exactly the same results in the log files, but the emails actually show up in the mailbox.  This tells me the spam filter is adding some header (or something) that is triggering the plesk_virtual mail system to drop the email.  Or something.

But this is where I've reached the limit of my server administration knowledge and would love some direction.

Edit.

```
-bash-4.2# postconf -n
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
authorized_flush_users =
authorized_mailq_users =
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 51200000
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
mynetworks =
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-3.5.14/README_FILES
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient,header_recipient
recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:12346
recipient_delimiter =
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-3.5.14/samples
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:12768
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /usr/local/psa/etc/dhparams2048.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtputf8_enable = no
tls_medium_cipherlist = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/certs
tls_ssl_options = no_compression
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:30
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
-bash-4.2# postconf -M
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
postlog    unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
plesk_virtual unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DORhu user=popuser:popuser argv=/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/postfix-local -f ${sender} -d ${recipient} -p /var/qmail/mailnames -q ${queue_id}
127.0.0.1:12346 inet n   n       n       -       -       spawn user=popuser:popuser argv=/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/postfix-srs
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=R user=mailman:mailman argv=/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/postfix-mailman ${nexthop} ${user} ${recipient}
pickup     fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       1       1       qmgr
smtps      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
plesk_saslauthd unix y   y       n       -       1       plesk_saslauthd status=5 listen=6 dbpath=/var/spool/postfix/plesk/passwd.db
plesk-158.69.12.128- unix - -    n       -       -       smtp -o smtp_bind_address=158.69.12.128 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4
plesk-54.39.48.83- unix - -      n       -       -       smtp -o smtp_bind_address=54.39.48.83 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4
-bash-4.2#
```

Comment: [Plesk (and similar systems) are off topic on ServerFault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055).

Comment: @vidarlo I believe this is far more email/postfix/dovecot related than control panel related.  I still completely disagree with that whole topic about not helping with control panel problems regardless mind you.  If this gets closed, then I guess it gets closed.

Comment: The problem is that the config is typically very non-standard and convoluted, which means that fault finding gets hard and the normal tricks doesn't work anymore. The fact that it is configured to deliver mail through a `plex_virtual` service points in this direction as well. And you don't give us any actual configuration to go on from anyway.

Comment: @vidarlo Yeah, that point I agree with.  As I mentioned though, that is where my knowledge comes to an end.  If there are specific things I can supply I'd be happy to get them but I don't know what those would be.

Comment: `main.cf` is the most important file when it comes to postfix delivery configuration.

Comment: @LukePittman Check the descriptions of the tags, you can use `postconf -n` and `postconf -M` to generate a well-formatted dump of your configuration (which may still be off-topic here, but at least you can utilize that to get an understanding of how messages traverse your setup, and how it differs from similar deployments), and you can use `journalctl` to search through structured logs, which may or may not include additional entries from services that are not configured to add their logs to the text logs at `/var/log/maillog`.

Comment: @anx Thank you.  Had no idea those commands existed.  Googling and learning now.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Added output of postconf -n and -M.  Continuing my search.

Answer (score 0):

You're hunting a ghost. The line "... status=sent (delivered via plesk_virtual service) ..." in your maillog is only logged when Plesk has for sure delivered the mail to a mailbox. It absolutely must be in that mailbox. If you do not find it there, another software, such as a client filter rule or download-and-remove-afterwards is removing it after it was delivered. Your log also does not include any SpamAssassin lines, so SA is not processing the mail.

Comment: Yes absolutely a ghost.  This is so frustrating.  I've tried removing all "scanners" (malware, virus, spam, etc) from the server in hopes if finding one that's doing it and it hasn't fixed it.  I'm at a complete loss.